# c# Dynamically create a table on webform based on query and add textboxes instead of values

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, dynamic

I am very new to C#. I have decided to develop a system, using webforms in C#, to record punter entries to a sweep for an annual competition. This is hopefully the best way to learn C# properly.

I can dynamically create the table on the webform based on a straightforward query which returns the home and away teams, with scores and other ancillary data. However, in order to use the same, or similar query, I need to create the same table which will insert textboxes, to replace the scores, which will be filled with the punters' predictions for scores for each game. There is a finite number of games.

Any and all helpful suggestions are welcome. Sarcasm and derogatory remarks are not appreciated as I assume you all can appreciate. If required, I can PM the SQL query to quickly build the database if required.

Here is my code so far:

**entry_form.aspx**

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="entry_form.aspx.cs" Inherits="Six_Nations_Championship.ShowData" %>



  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

  <head id="Head2" runat="server">
    <title>Six Nations Sweep - Entry Form</title>
    <link href="StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <form id="form2" runat="server">
      <div id="main_div">
        <div id="banner">
        </div>
        <div id="entry_form" class="form-style-9">
          <div id="Div4">
            <table>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <b class="field-style field-sptdt atdgn-left">First Name</b>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <asp:TextBox ID="FName" CssClass="textbox" runat="server" BackColor="White"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <b class="field-style field-sptdt atdgn-left">Last Name</b>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <asp:TextBox ID="LName" CssClass="textbox" runat="server" BackColor="White"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <b class="field-style field-sptdt atdgn-left">Mobile Number</b>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <asp:TextBox ID="Mobile" CssClass="textbox" runat="server" BackColor="White"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <b class="field-style field-sptdt atdgn-left">Email Address</b>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <asp:TextBox ID="Email" CssClass="textbox" runat="server" BackColor="White"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
          <table class="results">
            <tr>
              <td>
                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="DBDataPlaceHolder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>

  </html>
```

**entry_form.aspx.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;

namespace Six_Nations_Championship
{
            public partial class ShowData : System.Web.UI.Page
        {
            SqlDataAdapter da;
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            StringBuilder htmlTable = new StringBuilder();

            protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (!Page.IsPostBack)
                    BindData();
            }

            private void BindData()
            {
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
                con.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=SEAN_LAPTOP-HP;Initial Catalog=Six_Nations;Integrated Security=True";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT match_schedule.gameid AS Game, Home_Teams.country_name AS Home, match_schedule.home_country_score AS HomeScore,  match_schedule.away_country_score AS AwayScore, Away_Teams.country_name AS Away, match_schedule.venue, match_schedule.gametime AS Date FROM Away_Teams INNER JOIN match_schedule ON Away_Teams.away_teamid = match_schedule.away_teamid INNER JOIN Home_Teams ON match_schedule.home_teamid = Home_Teams.home_teamid", con);
                da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(ds);
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();

                htmlTable.Append("<table class='results'>");
                htmlTable.Append("<tr><th>Game ID</th><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Home</th><th>Score</th><th>Score</th><th>Away</th></tr>");

                if (!object.Equals(ds.Tables[0], null))
                {
                    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                    {

                        for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
                        {
                            htmlTable.Append("<tr style='color: White;'>");
                            htmlTable.Append("<td>" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Game"] + "</td>");
                            htmlTable.Append("<td>" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Home"] + "</td>");
                            htmlTable.Append("<td>" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["HomeScore"] + "</td>");
                            htmlTable.Append("<td>" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["AwayScore"] + "</td>");
                            htmlTable.Append("<td>" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Away"] + "</td>");
                            htmlTable.Append("<td>" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Venue"] + "</td>");
                            htmlTable.Append("<td>" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Date"] + "</td>");
                            htmlTable.Append("</tr>");
                        }
                        htmlTable.Append("</table>");
                        DBDataPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = htmlTable.ToString() });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        htmlTable.Append("<tr>");
                        htmlTable.Append("<td align='center' colspan='4'>There is no Record.</td>");
                        htmlTable.Append("</tr>");
                    }
                }
            }
            }
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish here. might be a good to check out this for some ideas on how to make this more clear. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You might want to google `GridView`

Comment: Thanks everyone. I ended up outputting the results of an SQL Query to a Datatable which does what I want. Just getting my head around all the different methods of displaying results and how and when to use them.